# call dynamic jquery function in objects

Tags: jquery, object, dynamic, call

Hello I found an article on stackoverflow how to call dynamic function:

```
function mainfunc(func) {
    this[func].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

This is very useful. But how can I call a function in my objects functions?

I get an error:

> "TypeError: this[func] is undefined
>   this[func].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));"

it looks like:

```
var myScript = {
...
add : function() {
...
myScript.ajax('url.php', params, 'myScript.add2List');
},

add2List : function(data) {
console.log(data);
},

ajax : function(url, params, func) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: params,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(func);
        mainfunc(func, data);
      }
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use that function, you could do the below instead.

```
var myScript = {
...
add : function() {
  ...
  myScript.ajax('url.php', params,  this.add2List);
},

add2List : function(data) {
  console.log(data);
},

ajax : function(url, params, func) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: params,
      success: func
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi xdazz. Thank you very much it works this way. But it doesn't work with "this" I had to write "myScript" instead. It couldn't find this - don't know ;)